# Using Algoliasearch Client JS Angular Module with RequireJS in a Rails Application

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3, requirejs, algolia

Even though the [Wiki](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js/wiki/Migration-guide-from-2.x.x-to-3.x.x#umd-compatibility) says it supports all major module loaders, I am unable to figure this one out. Googling is not yielding any helpful results.

I am trying to use [algoliasearch-client-js](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js/) (Angular build) in our existing Rails 3.2 application where in we use RequireJS for AMD support with pre-compilation.  I am using [requirejs-rails gem](https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails) and maintaining a requirejs.yml to manage paths config:

[image]

and this file is under the `/vendor` directory:

[image]

I am adding this to the angular module:

```
var app = angular.module('events', [
        'app.controllers',
        'app.directives',
        'app.filters',
        'app.factories',
        'app.services',
        'ngCookies',
        'algoliasearch'
    ]);
```

but still it is unable to find this module and looking at a wrong place:
[image]

This works locally but compiling the assets gives problems. Any pointers to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Syed, we can handle this in github and then post the answer here. https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js/issues/168

Comment: @vvo thanks, let us do that.